# Return to cursor position within table on page

Tags: javascript, php, html, scroll-position

Hi I am struggling with this. I have tried many of the numerous solutions posted here and elsewhere but cannot seem to get the functionality I need.

I have a fairly simple dynamic webpage which displays tabulated results. I only have a limited amount of freedom over what I can change within the page itself. When one of the links within the table is selected a second page loads which makes the appropriate changes in the database then returns to the first page. I am looking to return to the same position not only on the page itself but also within the scrolling table.

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
 <tr>
  <th style="width: 50px;">heading 1</th>
  <th style="width: 50px;">heading 2</th>
  <th style="width: 50px;">heading 3</th>
  <th style="width: 50px;">heading 4</th>
  <th style="width: 50px;">heading 5</th>
 </tr>
</table>

<table style="overflow-y: scroll;" id="maintable">

<!-- while loop populates second table from db typically ~50 rows -->

 <tr>
  <td style="width: 50px;"><a href="changeYN.php?link=1">Yes</a></td>
  <td style="width: 50px;"><a href="changeYN.php?link=2">Yes</a></td>
  <td style="width: 50px;"><a href="changeYN.php?link=3">Yes</a></td>
  <td style="width: 50px;"><a href="changeYN.php?link=4">Yes</a></td>
  <td style="width: 50px;"><a href="changeYN.php?link=5">Yes</a></td>
 </tr>
<!-- end of while loop -->
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to adapt the example given here [Refresh Page and Keep Scroll Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642872/refresh-page-and-keep-scroll-position) but ended up with a huge mess. I also tried the second solution on this page [Reload page in same position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280859/reload-page-in-same-position). Which does seem to affect the scroll position but doesn't seem to reflect the position in the table.

Comment: An modern alternative could be to use AJAX to submit the data without ever leaving the page.

Comment: Ok trying to get my head around AJAX. So if I change <a href="changeYN.php?link=1> to <a onclick="changeYN.php?link=1"> then sort out changeYN.php to make the db query and redraw the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to do this using JavaScript.

In this example I have given the table the id "maintable".
Each link within the table now has the following:

```
<a href="example.php" onclick="tablepos(this.id);">
```

My tablepos function is as follows:

```
function tablepos(clicked_id) {
var elmnt = document.getElementById("maintable");
var ytpos = elmnt.scrollTop;
var xtpos = elmnt.scrollLeft;
var yppos = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
var xppos = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
document.getElementById(clicked_id).href +="&xtpos=" + xtpos + "&ytpos=" + ytpos + "&xppos=" + xppos + "&yppos=" + yppos;
}
```

This appends the x and y scroll positions for the table (x/ytpos) and page (x/yppos) to the url which can then be picked up on the next page (or the same one if its self refering) with a

```
$ytpos=$_GET['ytpos'];
```

From there it can be handled as a normal php array.

To apply the positions to the page I have the following script after the table:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
document.getElementById("maintable").scrollTop = <?php echo $ytpos; ?>;
document.getElementById("maintable").scrollLeft = <?php echo $xtpos; ?>;
document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop = <?php echo $yppos; ?>;
document.documentElement.scrollLeft = document.body.scrollLeft = <?php echo $xppos; ?>;
});
</script>
```

This scrolls the table and page to the same positions.